# get MAx value of a column withing a fixed timestamp

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with timestamp and data in 12 columns. This data is dumped every second and I need to pick the MAX value of 6th column within every Minute. I am not even sure from were to start .I thought of doing as follow ,but do not know how to get one out of minute group. Also what if data is more then of 24 hours. so cannot use this approach. I think somehow I need to create a group of 60 rows and then sort data out of it, but not sure how to do that.

```
cat file |sort -k6  -r |awk '!a[$1]++' |sort -k1
```

For example :Input data

```
16:06:00       0    1.01    0.00    4.04    1.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   94.95
16:06:01       0    0.00    0.00    2.00    2.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   98.00
16:06:02       0    3.03    0.00    6.06    5.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   90.91
16:06:03       0    4.08    1.02    2.04    2.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   92.86
...
...
16:06:59       0    4.08    1.02    2.04    3.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   92.86
16:07:00       0    1.01    0.00    4.04    4.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   94.95
16:07:01       0    0.00    0.00    2.00    5.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   98.00
16:07:02       0    3.03    0.00    6.06    9.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   90.91
16:07:03       0    4.08    1.02    2.04    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   92.86
...
...
16:07:59       0    4.08    1.02    2.04    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   92.86
...
...
```

Expected output:

```
16:06:02       0    3.03    0.00    6.06    5.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   90.91
16:07:02       0    3.03    0.00    6.06    9.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   90.91
```

Comment: Use [`datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) with its `groupby` and `max` operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '        {split($1,a,":"); k=a[1]a[2]} 
     max[k]<$6 {max[k]=$6; maxR[k]=$0} 
     END       {for(r in maxR) print maxR[r]}' file

16:06:02       0    3.03    0.00    6.06    5.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   90.91
16:07:02       0    3.03    0.00    6.06    9.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   90.91
```

note that max is not initialized (implicitly initialized to zero), if values are all negative this is not going to work.  Workaround is simple but perhaps not needed in this context.

This alternative assumes time sorted records and prints the max in one minute intervals, so different dates will not be merged.

```
$ awk      '{split($1,a,":"); k=a[1]a[2]} 
     max<$6 {max=$6; maxR=$0} 
     p!=k   {if(p) print maxR; p=k} 
     END    {print maxR}' file 

16:06:02       0    3.03    0.00    6.06    5.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   90.91
16:07:02       0    3.03    0.00    6.06    9.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   90.91
```

Comment: does it distort the sorting ? I have 48hr+ data and timestamp is all jumbled up.

Comment: yes it shuffles the records based on array hashing, you need to sort the results based on first field.  Another alternative is printing the max after each minute change, perhaps it fits better.

Comment: In that case I will have two 16:00:00 for day 1 and another for day2

Comment: right, but if you don't have the date field you've already in trouble.

Comment: its `mpstat` output :(

Comment: I split the file using `00:00:00` as a separator . And then applied your solution its working now. Thanks.

Comment: check the second version, it should work with multiple dates as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
$ cat monk.log
16:06:00       0    1.01    0.00    4.04    1.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   94.95
16:06:01       0    0.00    0.00    2.00    2.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   98.00
16:06:02       0    3.03    0.00    6.06    5.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   90.91
16:06:03       0    4.08    1.02    2.04    2.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   92.86
16:06:59       0    4.08    1.02    2.04    3.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   92.86
16:07:00       0    1.01    0.00    4.04    4.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   94.95
16:07:01       0    0.00    0.00    2.00    5.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   98.00
16:07:02       0    3.03    0.00    6.06    9.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   90.91
16:07:03       0    4.08    1.02    2.04    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   92.86
16:07:59       0    4.08    1.02    2.04    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   92.86


$ perl -F'/\s+/' -lane '  $F[0]=~/(.*):/ and $x=$1 ; if( $F[5]>$kv{$x} ) { $kv{$x}=$F[5]; $kv2{$x}=$_ } END { print "$kv2{$_}" for(keys %kv) } ' monk.log
16:06:02       0    3.03    0.00    6.06    5.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   90.91
16:07:02       0    3.03    0.00    6.06    9.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   90.91
```

or

```
$ perl -F'/\s+/' -lane '  $F[0]=~/(.*):/ ; if( $F[5]>$kv{$1} ) { $kv{$1}=$F[5]; $kv2{$1}=$_ } END { print "$kv2{$_}" for(keys %kv) } ' monk.log
16:07:02       0    3.03    0.00    6.06    9.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   90.91
16:06:02       0    3.03    0.00    6.06    5.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   90.91
```

Answer (score 0):

awk + sort

```
$ cat monk.log
16:06:00       0    1.01    0.00    4.04    1.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   94.95
16:06:01       0    0.00    0.00    2.00    2.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   98.00
16:06:02       0    3.03    0.00    6.06    5.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   90.91
16:06:03       0    4.08    1.02    2.04    2.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   92.86
16:06:59       0    4.08    1.02    2.04    3.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   92.86
16:07:00       0    1.01    0.00    4.04    4.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   94.95
16:07:01       0    0.00    0.00    2.00    5.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   98.00
16:07:02       0    3.03    0.00    6.06    9.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   90.91
16:07:03       0    4.08    1.02    2.04    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   92.86
16:07:59       0    4.08    1.02    2.04    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   92.86

$ awk ' { split($1,t,":"); $(NF+1)=t[1]t[2] }1 ' monk.log | sort -k12 -n -k6  | awk ' !a[$NF] { a[$NF]++ ; NF--; print} '
16:06:02 0 3.03 0.00 6.06 5.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 90.91
16:07:02 0 3.03 0.00 6.06 9.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 90.91
```

or

```
$ awk ' split($1,t,":") && $(NF+1)=t[1]t[2] ' monk.log | sort -k12 -n -k6  | awk ' !a[$NF] { a[$NF]++ ; NF--; print} '
16:06:02 0 3.03 0.00 6.06 5.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 90.91
16:07:02 0 3.03 0.00 6.06 9.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 90.91
```